# Cannot resolve scoped service DbContextOptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, middleware

I been searching around now for a clear cut answer on this issue, including github and still cannot see what I am missing here:

Cannot resolve scoped service '***Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[PureGateway.Data.GatewayContext]***' from root provider.

In Startup.cs:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //other code omitted for brevity

            var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            services.AddDbContext<GatewayContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
            services.AddDbContextPool<GatewayContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
            services.AddScoped<IGatewayRepository, GatewayRepository>();
        }
```

Usage:

```
public sealed class MatchBrokerRouteMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<MatchBrokerRouteMiddleware> _logger;

    public MatchBrokerRouteMiddleware(
        RequestDelegate next,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MatchBrokerRouteMiddleware>();
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, GatewayContext gatewayContext)
    {
            await _next(context);
    }
```

***I am using netcore 2.2.***

Comment: inject into `GatewayContext` into `MatchBrokerRouteMiddleware`

Comment: this can only be done at the method invoke level - read this on GitHub.

Comment: Anybody know if you can inject any type into MW ctor or Invoke() ? Assuming it has been registered ofc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you either need to use `AddDbContext` or `AddDbContextPool`, not both of them.

---

DbContextPool needs single public constructor. Check my Example below:

```
public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IUserResolverService _userResolverService;

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        _userResolverService = this.GetService<IUserResolverService>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - i was following a blog post where i saw that. :S

Am now dealing with: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The DbContext of type 'GatewayContext' cannot be pooled 
because it does not have a single public constructor accepting a single parameter of type DbContextOptions.'

Comment: Found it - auto gen'ed default ctor.

Answer (score 15):

I had this same error but found the issue was to do with service lifetime of the DbContextOptions object. By default it is "Scoped" (ie created for each request), whereas the factory expects it to be singleton.

As per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65022730/120297), the fix was to explicitly set the options lifetime:

```
services.AddDbContext<GatewayContext>(options => ApplyOurOptions(options, connectionString),
    contextLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Scoped, 
    optionsLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```

Comment: I have searched for whole day for a solution and this one resolved it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you really need it then you can, the idea is to register as a last line DB options again, since AddPooledDbContextFactory cleans it up. And do not forget to keep only 1 constructor in your DbContext (only this: public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)):

```
DbContextOptionsBuilder MsSQL(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder) =>
                builder.UseSqlServer(settings.ConnectionString, x => x.UseNetTopologySuite());
services
    .AddPooledDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>(options => MsSQL(options))
    .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => MsSQL(options))
    .AddScoped<IMyDbContext>(provider => provider.GetService<MyDbContext>())
    .AddSingleton(factory => MsSQL(new DbContextOptionsBuilder()).Options);
```