# Use both AddDbContextFactory() and AddDbContext() extension methods in the same project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, ef-core-3.1, ef-core-5.0

I'm trying to use the new `DbContextFactory` pattern discussed in [the DbContext configuration section of the EF Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor).

I've got the `DbContextFactory` up and running successfully in my Blazor app, but I want to retain the option to inject instances of `DbContext` directly in order to keep my existing code working.

However, when I try to do that, I'm getting an error along the lines of:

> System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be
> constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor
> 'ServiceType:
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory`1[MyContext] Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextFactory`1[MyContext]':
> Cannot consume scoped service
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[MyContext]' from singleton 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory`1[MyContext]'.) --->
> System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service
> descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory`1[MyContext] Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextFactory`1[MyContext]':
> Cannot consume scoped service
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[MyContext]' from singleton 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory`1[MyContext]'. --->
> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[MyContext]' from singleton 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory`1[MyContext]'.

I also managed to get this error at one point while experimenting:

> Cannot resolve scoped service
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[MyContext]' from
> root provider.

Is it theoretically possible to use both `AddDbContext` and `AddDbContextFactory` together?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It is, it's all about understanding the lifetimes of the various elements in play and getting those set correctly.

By default the `DbContextFactory` created by the `AddDbContextFactory()` extension method has a Singleton lifespan.  If you use the `AddDbContext()` extension method with it's default settings it will create a `DbContextOptions` with a `Scoped` lifespan ([see the source-code here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/243357978bfa9b457e5e5011ea13648c46d8a1e8/src/EFCore/Extensions/EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L534)), and as a `Singleton` can't use something with a shorter `Scoped` lifespan, an error is thrown.

To get round this, we need to change the lifespan of the `DbContextOptions` to also be 'Singleton'.  This can be done using by explicitly setting the scope of the `DbContextOptions` parameter of `AddDbContext()`

```cs
services.AddDbContext<FusionContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(YourSqlConnection),
    optionsLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```

There's a really good discussion of this [on the EF core GitHub repository starting here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/pull/21246#issuecomment-668093047).  It's also well worth having a look at the source-code for `DbContextFactory` [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore/Internal/DbContextFactory.cs).

Alternatively, you can also change the lifetime of the `DbContextFactory` by [setting the ServiceLifetime parameter in the constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontextfactory?view=efcore-5.0):

```cs
services.AddDbContextFactory<FusionContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(YourSqlConnection), 
    ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

The options should be configured exactly [as you would for a normal DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/) as those are the options that will be set on the DbContext the factory creates.

Comment: This answer is very useful to people who are upgrading to .NET 5 and are looking to use Blazor and MVC Core in the same project, although I do not know what ApplyOurOptions is. If that isn't a part of EF that I'm unaware of, perhaps consider converting this to use normal options?

Comment: Hi @BrianMacKay, that was exactly our situation. Sorry, `ApplyOurOptions` is a helper function from our code, I've changed the code and added some clarification.

Comment: @tomRedux I bet prior to .NET 5, you had to do the same thing as me and figure out how to implement your own AddDbContextFactory extension. Good times. :)

Comment: One caveat: If you're using `options.AddInterceptors(...)` with `AddDbContext` alone you'll get a new instance of each interceptor for every new Scoped context (because interceptors are created along with options). So generally this means for each web request you'd get clean interceptors. However if you switch to using `AddDbContextFactory` you'll now be able to create multiple independent contexts, but they'll all share inteceptors (via the shared options). This is fine if your interceptors are completely thread safe, but be careful if they aren't!

Comment: ... this is because for `AddDbContextFactory` there's no way you can specify `optionsLifetime` to be different from `contextLifetime` (at least if there is let me know!). There's a similar situation for pooling.

Comment: @BrianMacKay And even in 2022 this answer is still useful, as Blazor still used standard Razor Pages for the whole ASP.NET Core Identity thing! I scaffolded those in my Blazor app and found out that way- Horrible!

Comment: @Zimano Yes, I feel that using Auth0 / Okta  (maybe Identity Server) is a better pattern. Especially great for being able to tell compliance auditors that the password never passes through your system, and having your login page super hardened because that's all these folks do. It does bring some complexity with it however.

Comment: Your sample code for `AddDbContext` has `contextLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Transient`. There's nothing wrong with this, but it's different than the default, which is scoped. Since the focus is the options lifetime, you may want to leave the service lifetime as the default in your example to avoid confusion (i.e., remove the line with `contextLifetime`).

Comment: @EdwardBrey good point, I've done that now.

Answer (score 14):

**Important point:**

Both `AddDbContextFactory` and `AddDbContext` internally register the `DbContextOptions<T>` inside a shared private method `AddCoreServices` using `TryAdd`. ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/7a7df5fe61529a97a0d96af4c9780f99e5705630/src/EFCore/Extensions/EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L924))

Which effectively means whichever one is in your code *first* is the one that gets used.

So you can actually do this for a cleaner setup:

```
services.AddDbContext<RRStoreContext>(options => {

   // apply options

});

services.AddDbContextFactory<RRStoreContext>(lifetime: ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

I'm using the following to prove to myself it really does function like that:

```
services.AddDbContextFactory<RRStoreContext>(options =>
{
   throw new Exception("Oops!");  // this should never be reached

}, ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

Unfortunately I have some query interceptors that aren't thread safe (which is the whole reason I wanted to make multiple instances with a factory), so I think I'll need to make my own context factory because I have separate initialization for Context vs. ContextFactory.

---

Edit: I ended u making my own context factory to be able to create new options for every new context that was created. The only reason was to allow for non-thread safe interceptors, but if you need that or something similar then this should work.

Influenced by: [DbContextFactory](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore/Internal/DbContextFactory.cs)

```
public class SmartRRStoreContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<RRStoreContext>
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public SmartRRStoreContextFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public virtual RRStoreContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        // need a new options object for each 'factory generated' context
        // because of thread safety isuess with Interceptors
        var options = (DbContextOptions<RRStoreContext>) _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(DbContextOptions<RRStoreContext>));
        return new RRStoreContext(options);
    }
}
```

Note: I only have one context that needs this so I'm hardcoding the new context in my `CreateDbContext` method. The alternative would be to use reflection - something like this [DbContextFactorySource](http://DbContextFactorySource).

Then in my Startup.cs I have:

```
services.AddDbContext<RRStoreContext>(options => 
{
    var connection = CONNECTION_STRING;

    options.UseSqlServer(connection, sqlOptions =>
    {
        sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure();
    });

    // this is not thread safe
    options.AddInterceptors(new RRSaveChangesInterceptor());

}, optionsLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Transient);

// add context factory, this uses the same options builder that was just defined
// but with a custom factory to force new options every time
services.AddDbContextFactory<RRStoreContext, SmartRRStoreContextFactory>();
```

And I'll end with a warning. If you're using a factory (`CreateDbContext`) in additional to a 'normal' injected DbContext make extra sure not to mix entities. If for instance you call SaveChanges on the wrong context then your entities won't get saved.

Comment: that's really interesting, thank you.  I'll have a look at that.  I think I'll do exactly the same with the exception to help remind me what's going on!

Comment: Basically spent the whole day sort of exploring this and some surrounding issues with async. Managed to save 1 second from an operation that takes 1.5 seconds. It runs once a day so that's about 6 minutes a year I'm saving :-)

Comment: Wow, thanks for this. I was surprised to see this behaviour. It feels like .NET should be tracking which options to use for different "requesters"; I'm glad that in my case, the options are the same whether using the ContextPool or the ContextFactory.

Comment: @Jarvis it's just tracked by dependency injection with the generic type name `DbContextOptions<MyContextName>` - so whether the factory or the non-factory requests it you'll get the same options (and the scope determines whether or not it's a shared copy)

Comment: Hmm, when using AddDbContext with transient lifetime it might leak types. Normally the scoped lifetime is used for DbContext because it's calling dispose after scope ends. But when one uses transient the user must call the dispose I think, and it might leak?

Comment: @Ciantic I usually do (using var db = new ...) from years of habit - so this quite likely may be true and I'm already working around it! I wonder how to know for sure.

Comment: @Ciantic No, Dispose() is called at end-of-request for both Scoped and Transient.  The difference is Scoped the same instance will be given to multiple objects.  This is nice if you want all users of EF to use the same cache for Find(), but still surprises me often.  Transient each service (repository and Controller) will get different EF context objects, even for same type.  But in both cases they are disposed at the end of request.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40844151/when-are-net-core-dependency-injected-instances-disposed

Answer (score 8):

Sarting with EF Core 6 (.NET 6) you don't need to use both in most cases, since `AddDbContextFactory` also registers the context type itself as a scoped service.

So in services with `Singleton` lifetime inject `IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>`, and in services with `Scoped` lifetime (e.g. MVC or API controllers) inject `MyDbContext` directly.

If you want to use different `DbContextOptions` in each case or if the `Singleton` lifetime of `DbContextOptions` do not fit your needs, you have to go with the solutions provided by the other answers.

See also:
[Related Github enhancement issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/25164)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error, but I solved it in a different way, because for AddDbContextFactory I needed Sigleton.
I added the services in a different order, first AddDbContextFactory and then AddDbContext. Here's what it looks like in my code:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(connectionString, c => c.UseNodaTime()));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(connectionString, c => c.UseNodaTime()));
```