# Blazor Server: Mixing EF Core DbContextFactory with DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor, .net-5

I am building a Blazor Server front end to an existing domain layer. This layer offers various injectable services to do modifications on the EF Core repository. For this, the services itself requests a DbContext from the (standard Microsoft) DI container. This works fine with regular ASP.NET MVC / Razor pages with a scoped DbContext instance, but as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-5.0), this is problematic with Blazor. In a Blazor Server app we’d want to use DbContextFactory to generate short-lived DbContext instances for operations instead.

It’s no problem to have both a DbContext and DbContextFactory in the same application, but I’m struggling to understand how to adapt my services. Or if I even need to? To illustrate, this is the current code:

My page:

```
@page “/items”
@inject ItemService ItemService

// somewhere in the code
    ItemService.DoOperation(…)
```

My service

```cs
class ItemService
{
    public ItemService(MyDbContext myDbContext)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public bool DoOperation(…)
    {
        // ...
        _myDbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => ...),
            contextLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Transient,
            optionsLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Singleton);

services.AddDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>(options => ...);
```

I’ve changed the lifetimes for DbContext according to the example given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65022730/606167) and so far I haven’t been able to create any issues, but I don’t fully understand the lifetime issues at play here. How can I engineer my service to play well in both a Blazor and an ASP.NET MVC/Razor pages application in an obvious way?

Comment: Just an update: in EF Core 6, AddDbContextFactory now also registers DbContext so no need to inject them separately anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is transitive: Your services rely on a should-be-scoped resource and that only works when you register those services as scoped as well. Which you can't.

The proper way is to rewrite your services to the DbContext per Operation model, and inject the DbContextFactory.

It looks like you already have a mixed model (with a SaveChanges per operation they are actually a UoW).

When you don't want to make those changes you could weasel your way out by registering the DbContext as Transient. That feels bad but it's designed to quickly release the underlying connection. So it's not the resource leak that it looks like.

Answer (score 9):

In your typical MVC application, one request represents a single unit of work. The DbContext is generated as a scoped service and injected through the constructor. This is fine.

On the other hand, in Blazor Server one request no longer represents a single unit of work. The first request creates a circuit which means that any scoped service injected is going to have a lifetime as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly#service-lifetime).

In Blazor Server apps, a unit of work is a SignalR message. (a button click for example that adds a new row to the database). Because of this, injecting your context directly [is not the way to go](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-5.0#database-access-5x).

That's why Blazor Server has `IDbContextFactory<T>`. Initialize it like this:

```cs
services.AddDbContextFactory<DbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebDB")));
```

In your Razor Components (tied to the Blazor app) you use it like so:

```cs
private readonly IDbContextFactory<DbContext> factory;

public Component(IDbContextFactory<DbContext> f)
{
    factory = f;
}

public void Click()
{
    using(DbContext cnt = factory.CreateDbContext())
    {
    // Your code here
    }
}
```

This is further explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-5.0#new-dbcontext-instances-5x).

Documentation: [ASP.NET Core Blazor Server with Entity Framework Core (EFCore)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: Yes, so this is what I'm doing now for direct access of EF Core from Blazor. The problem lies in existing services I use that currently inject DbContext instead of DbContextFactory.  This must be a common problem, yet I see nobody talking about it.

Comment: [Polite] Why would you access the database directly through EF from a component?  This ties the component to Blazor Server, which in my (personal) design book is a no no.  I know the MS Docs link shows doing that, but ....

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I am just showing the official documentation. Personally, I would create a separate service for data access and inject that wherever I need it. All in all is up to the developer what method they use.

Comment: @Grizzlly - Glad to hear. :-)

Comment: @martijn what is the correct way to use with services

Comment: @Sebastian with EF Core 6 this has now been improved https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/whatsnew#dbcontext-factory-improvements

Comment: @Martijn so how you adapted your services for use in Blazor Server Side?
you get a dbcontext from factory.CreateDbContext() in every method of your page and pass to your service (with a using to dispose)? or you do only once in OnInitialized/OnParameterSet ?

And is UnitOfWork still working? I mean not only when I update a property of the Model, but eg. when I add an item to its ICollection<T> (that should create a record in the many-to-many join table)?

Comment: In my opinion, accessing DbContext directly from the component is only acceptable for very simple use-cases. In a complex architecture, where there are multiple services calling each other, each needing access to the *same* DbContext instance (ex. BlogService calling PostService), this approach doesn't work. All of the services *must* receive the same instance of DbContext for it to work properly. I've been searching for possible solutions online, but haven't found anything useful. It is one of the most fundamental architectural approaches, yet there aren't any real solutions out there.

Answer (score 0):

my practice:
set dbcontext use database type

```
services.AddScoped<AuditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor>();
    if (configuration.GetValue<bool>("UseInMemoryDatabase"))
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseInMemoryDatabase("BlazorDashboardDb");
            options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        });
    }
    else
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(
                  configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                  builder =>
                  {
                      builder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName);
                      builder.EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: 5,
                                                   maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                                                   errorNumbersToAdd: null);
                      builder.CommandTimeout(15);
                  });
            options.EnableDetailedErrors(detailedErrorsEnabled: true);
            options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        });
        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
    }
```

as we know DbContext should be transient lifetime in blazor server.

```
 services.AddTransient<IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>, BlazorContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>>();
 services.AddTransient<IApplicationDbContext>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>>().CreateDbContext());
```

as sample, not change use DbContext:

```
 public class AddEditCustomerCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<AddEditCustomerCommand, Result<int>>
{
    private readonly IApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<AddEditCustomerCommandHandler> _localizer;
    public AddEditCustomerCommandHandler(
        IApplicationDbContext context,
        IStringLocalizer<AddEditCustomerCommandHandler> localizer,
        IMapper mapper
        )
    {
        _context = context;
        _localizer = localizer;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is BlazorContextFactory and what is this line for:
services.AddTransient<IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>, BlazorContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>>();