DbContext is disposed after navigate
I'm developing a blazor web app and I'm facing a weird behaviour. Almost all pages are a copy/paste, they have CRUD operations and a previous list of differents elements (seasons, player, fixtures, etc...) but only in one of them I'm having problems. When I click on the 'Edit' button of a player I'm getting a 'Cannot access a disposed object' referring to the _dbContext.
Adding a breakpoint to the DisposeAsync() method I've discovered that it's been fired when I navigate to the edit page. But only happens in player's page, not in any of the other pages.
Here's the players page:
@page "/players"
@attribute [Authorize]

@using Models = Biwenger.Models
@using Biwenger.Services
@inject PlayersService service;
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager;

<h3>Jugadores</h3>

<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/player" role="button">Añadir</a>

<div class="mb-3 lg-6">
    <label for="search" class="form-label">Buscar Jugador:</label>
    <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" @bind="searchTerm" @oninput="FilterPlayers" placeholder="Escribe el nombre del jugador..." />
</div>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
            <th scope="col">Equipo</th>
            <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (filteredList.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in filteredList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">@item.Id</th>
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.Team.Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => EditPlayer(item.Id, item.TeamId)">Editar</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="text-center">No hay registros.</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@code {

    List<Models.Player> fullList = new List<Models.Player>();
    List<Models.Player> filteredList = new List<Models.Player>();
    string searchTerm = "";

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        fullList = await service.GetAllPlayers();
        filteredList = fullList;
    }

    private void FilterPlayers()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
        {
            filteredList = fullList;
        } else
        {
            filteredList = fullList.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                .ToList();
        }

        StateHasChanged();
    }
    
    private void EditPlayer(int id, int teamId)
    {
        navigationManager.NavigateTo($"/player/{id}/{teamId}");  <-- Here calls for dispose
    }
}

This is the page I'm navigating to:
@page "/player/{id:int?}/{teamId:int?}"
@attribute [Authorize]

@using Biwenger.Models.ViewModels
@using Biwenger.Services

@inject ILogger<Player> Logger
@inject PlayersService service
@inject TeamsService teamsService
@inject SeasonsService seasonsService;
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<PageTitle>Equipo</PageTitle>

<h3>@(model?.PlayerId == 0 ? "Nuevo Jugador" : "Editar Jugador")</h3>

<EditForm EditContext="editContext" OnValidSubmit="Submit" FormName="form">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <div class="col-mb-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <label for="name" class="form-label">Nombre</label>
        <input id="name" class="form-control" @bind="model!.Name" @onblur="CheckIfNameExists" @ref="nameInput"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-mb-3 col-lg-6">
        <ValidationMessage For="() => model!.Name"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div class="col-mb-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <label for="team" class="form-label">Equipo</label>
        <InputSelect id="team" class="form-control" @bind-Value="model!.TeamId">
            <option value="">Seleccione un equipo</option>
            @foreach (Models.Team team in listTeams)
            {
                <option value="@(team.Id)">@team.Name</option>
            }
        </InputSelect>
    </div>
    <div class="col-mb-3 col-lg-6">
        <ValidationMessage For="() => model!.TeamId"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div class="col-mb-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <label for="team" class="form-label">Posición</label>
        @if (positionsItems != null)
        {
        <BootstrapSelect
            TItem="Models.DropdownItem<String>"
            Data="@positionsItems"
            @bind-Value="model!.Position"
            TextField="@((item) => item.Value)"
            ValueField="@((item) => item.Key.ToString())"
            TType="Biwenger.Enums.Positions">
        </BootstrapSelect>
            
        }
    </div>
    <div class="col-mb-3 col-lg-6">
        <ValidationMessage For="() => model!.TeamId"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div class="col-mb-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <label for="cost" class="form-label">Coste @currentSeason!.Name</label>
        <input type="number" id="cost" @bind="currentPlayerCost!.Cost" min="1" class="form-control text-end" @ref="costInput" @onfocus="selectAllText" @onblur="addMillions" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="@model!.Black" id="checkBlack" @bind="model!.Black" />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="checkBlack"> Es negro</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="@model!.Active" id="checkActive" @bind="model!.Active" />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="checkActive"> Activo</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-mb-3 col-lg-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary ms-2" @onclick="GoBack">Volver</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn @buttonClass" disabled="@(!editContext?.Validate() ?? false || isLoading)">
            @if (isLoading)
            {
                <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Enviando...</span>
            }
            else if (showSuccess)
            {
                <span>Guardado...</span>
            }
            else if (showError)
            {
                <span>Error...</span>
            }
            else
            {
                <span>Enviar</span>
            }
        </button>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private EditContext? editContext;
    private ElementReference nameInput;
    private ElementReference costInput;
    private Biwenger.Models.Season? currentSeason;
    private Biwenger.Models.PlayerSeasonCost? currentPlayerCost;

    [Parameter]
    public int? id { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public int? teamId { get; set; }

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private PlayerWithCostViewModel? model { get; set; }

    private List<Models.Team> listTeams = new List<Models.Team>();

    private ValidationMessageStore? messageStore;

    private bool isLoading = false;
    private bool showSuccess = false;
    private bool showError = false;

    private string buttonClassSuccess = "btn-success";
    private string buttonClassError = "btn-danger";
    private string buttonClassIdle = "btn-primary";
    private string buttonClass = "btn-primary";

    IList<Models.DropdownItem<String>> positionsItems;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        positionsItems = new List<Models.DropdownItem<String>>
        {
            new Models.DropdownItem<String> { Key = 0, Value = "Posición" },
            new Models.DropdownItem<String> { Key = 1, Value = "PT" },
            new Models.DropdownItem<String> { Key = 2, Value = "DF" },
            new Models.DropdownItem<String> { Key = 3, Value = "MC" },
            new Models.DropdownItem<String> { Key = 4, Value = "DL" },
        };

        editContext = new EditContext(model ??= new PlayerWithCostViewModel());
        currentSeason = seasonsService.GetCurrentSeason();
        currentPlayerCost = new Models.PlayerSeasonCost();
        listTeams = await teamsService.GetAllTeams();

        if (id.HasValue && id.Value > 0)
        {
            model = await service.GetPlayerWithCostById(id.Value, teamId!.Value);
            if (model != null)
            {
                editContext = new EditContext(model);
            }
        }

        messageStore = new ValidationMessageStore(editContext);
    }

    private async void CheckIfNameExists()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model!.Name))
        {
            bool exists = await service!.NameExists(model!.Name, id, model!.TeamId);

            messageStore?.Clear(() => model.Name);

            if (exists)
            {
                messageStore?.Clear();
                messageStore?.Add(() => model.Name, "El nombre ya existe");

            }

            editContext?.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
        }
    }

    private void GoBack()
    {
        navigationManager.NavigateTo("/players");
    }

    private async Task Submit()
    {
        isLoading = true;
        Logger.LogInformation("Se ha llamado a submit");

        bool success = false;

        if (editContext!.Validate())
        {
            if (id.HasValue && id.Value > 0)
            {
                success = await service.UpdatePlayer(model!, currentSeason!.Id);
            }
            else
            {
                if (model!.Costs!.Count == 0)
                {
                    model!.Costs.Add(new Models.PlayerSeasonCost()
                        {
                            Cost = currentPlayerCost!.Cost,
                            SeasonId = currentSeason!.Id,
                            TeamId = model!.TeamId
                        });
                }

                success = await service!.AddPlayer(model!);
            }

            isLoading = false;

            if (success)
            {
                showSuccess = true;
                buttonClass = buttonClassSuccess;

                StateHasChanged();

                await Task.Delay(3000);

                showSuccess = false;
                buttonClass = buttonClassIdle;

                StateHasChanged();

                if (!id.HasValue)
                {
                    model = new PlayerWithCostViewModel();
                    editContext = new EditContext(model);
                    messageStore = new ValidationMessageStore(editContext);
                    messageStore.Clear();
                }

                model!.Name = "";
                model.TeamId = 0;
                currentPlayerCost = new Models.PlayerSeasonCost();
                model!.Black = false;
                model!.Active = true;


                StateHasChanged();
                await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("focusElement", nameInput);
            }
            else
            {
                showSuccess = true;
                buttonClass = buttonClassError;

                await Task.Delay(1000);

                showSuccess = false;
                buttonClass = buttonClassIdle;
            }
        }

    }

    private async Task selectAllText()
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("selectElementText", costInput);
    }

    private void addMillions()
    {
        if (currentPlayerCost!.Cost < 100)
        {
            currentPlayerCost.Cost = currentPlayerCost.Cost * 1000000;
        }
    }
}

And the playersService:
using Biwenger.Data;
using Biwenger.Models;
using Biwenger.Models.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Biwenger.Services
{
    public class PlayersService
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

        public PlayersService(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public async Task<List<Player>> GetAllPlayers()
        {
            return await _dbContext.Players.Include(p => p.Team).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<List<Player>> GetAllActivePlayers()
        {
            return await _dbContext.Players.Where(p => p.Active == true).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        }


        public async Task<bool> AddPlayer(PlayerWithCostViewModel player)
        {
            var strategy = _dbContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
            bool result = false;

            await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
            {
                var transaction = await _dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
                
                try
                {
                    var newPlayer = new Player
                    {
                        Active = player.Active,
                        Black = player.Black,
                        TeamId = player.TeamId,
                        Name = player.Name,
                        Position = player.Position,
                    };

                    await _dbContext.Players.AddAsync(newPlayer);


                    var playerSeasonCost = new PlayerSeasonCost
                    {
                        Cost = player.Costs!.First().Cost,
                        TeamId = player.TeamId,
                        PlayerId = newPlayer.Id,
                        SeasonId = player.Costs!.First().SeasonId,
                    };

                    await _dbContext.PlayersSeasonsCost.AddAsync(playerSeasonCost);
                    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();


                    await transaction.CommitAsync();
                    result = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    await transaction.RollbackAsync();

                    result = false;
                }
            });

            return result;
        }

        public async Task<bool> UpdatePlayer(PlayerWithCostViewModel player, int seasonId)
        {
            Player? currentPlayer = await _dbContext.Players.FindAsync(player.PlayerId);

            if (currentPlayer == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var transaction = await _dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();

            try
            {
                currentPlayer.Name = player.Name;
                currentPlayer.Black = player.Black;
                currentPlayer.Position = player.Position;
                currentPlayer.Active = player.Active;
                currentPlayer.TeamId = player.TeamId;

                _dbContext.Players.Update(currentPlayer);
                await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                
                await transaction.CommitAsync();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await transaction.RollbackAsync();
                return false;
            }
        }

        public async Task<Player?> GetPlayerByid(int id)
        {
            return await _dbContext.Players.FindAsync(id);
        }

        public async Task<PlayerWithCostViewModel?> GetPlayerWithCostById(int playerId, int teamId)
        {
            try
            {

                Player? player = await _dbContext.Players
                    .Include(p => p.PlayersSeasonsCost)
                    .Where(p => p.Id == playerId && p.TeamId == teamId)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(); <-- Already _dbContext Disposed

                if (player == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                List<PlayerSeasonCost>? pscList = await _dbContext.PlayersSeasonsCost.Where(psc => psc.PlayerId == playerId).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

                PlayerWithCostViewModel pwcvm = new PlayerWithCostViewModel
                {
                    PlayerId = playerId,
                    TeamId = teamId,
                    Active = player.Active,
                    Black = player.Black,
                    Position = player.Position,
                    Name = player.Name,
                    Costs = pscList ??= new List<PlayerSeasonCost>()
                };

                return pwcvm;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }

        public async Task<bool> NameExists(string name, int? id, int teamId)
        {
            if (id.HasValue && id.Value > 0)
            {
                return await _dbContext.Players.AnyAsync(t => t.Name == name && t.TeamId == teamId && t.Id != id);
            }

            return await _dbContext.Players.AnyAsync(t => t.Name == name && t.TeamId == teamId);
        }

        public async Task<List<PlayerWithCurrentCostVM>> GetPlayersWithCurrentCost()
        {
            List<PlayerWithCurrentCostVM> pwcc = new List<PlayerWithCurrentCostVM>();

            pwcc = await _dbContext.Players.Include(p => p.PlayersSeasonsCost)
                    .ThenInclude(psc => psc.Season)
                    .Where(p => p.Active == true)
                    .Select(p => new PlayerWithCurrentCostVM
                    {
                        Player = p,
                        Name = p.Name,
                        Cost = p.PlayersSeasonsCost == null ? 0 : p.PlayersSeasonsCost.Where(psc => psc.Season.Active == true).First().Cost
                    }) 
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .ToListAsync();

            return pwcc;
        }

    }
}


What is the life span of your PlayerService ?
DbContext are scoped service. If you want to consume it in a singleton, you need to create a scope each time you want to use the dbContext:
using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
using var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
Depending if your pages are server hosted or wasm, the scope may change when you navigate to other page

Also this can come from the OnInitialized method of your edit page.
Your're creating a default model, create an EditContext, then call an async method (the component will render), then continue to retrive the model from your service, and create e new editContext. But because of the await (await teamsService.GetAllTeams()), the component is rendering, and you are changing the references of the EC and the model.
Try to modify the OnInitialize method to first retrive / create the model, then create the editContext only once. You'll need to add a big @if (model != null) in your razor code

Instead of injecting a DbContext, you may need to inject a DbContextFactory. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/67374706/121309

On a side note, var transaction = should be using var transaction =

Heed this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-8.0

That var transaction = await _dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(); is a critical bug. DbContext isn't a database connection, it's a Unit-of-Work using optimistic concurrency. SaveChanges persists all pending changes inside an internal database transaction.  The Add and Update methods don't add or update individual rows, they "only" attach objects in the Added or Modified state. It's SaveChanges that executes the actual INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE commands for all objects

.AsNoTracking(). is also a bug if you intend to modify the loaded entities. If you let EF Core's change tracking to work, you won't need any Update calls. When you call SaveChanges all changes to the tracked objects will be detected and persisted

Finally, the problem was in this part of the code:
 <BootstrapSelect
            TItem="Models.DropdownItem<String>"
            Data="@positionsItems"
            @bind-Value="model!.Position"
            TextField="@((item) => item.Value)"
            ValueField="@((item) => item.Key.ToString())"
            TType="Biwenger.Enums.Positions">
        </BootstrapSelect>

It seems that BootsatrpSelect doesn't work well with Generic types or Enums. Binded it to a int variable and the problem dissapears.
Thank you all for your feedback
