# Scoped service in DBContext with DBContextFactory can't resolve from root provider

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I want to register a scoped `ICurrentUserService` and then use it in the DbContext to set the `CreatedBy` property on every entity. I want it scoped because it uses the current `HttpContext` to get the user id from the claims and the HttpContext is scoped by definition.

```cs
services.AddTransient<ICurrentUserService, CurrentUserService>();
```

However when I try to use this with the DbContextFactory like this:

```cs
services.AddDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(config.ConnectionStrings.MSSQLConnection, x =>
        {
            x.MigrationsHistoryTable("...");
            x.MigrationsAssembly("...");
        }));

services.AddScoped<IMyDbContext>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>>().CreateDbContext());
services.AddScoped<MyDbContext>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>>().CreateDbContext());
```

I get the error

> Cannot resolve scoped service 'SomeNamespace.ICurrentUserService' from root provider.

I can change it to Transient but that seems wrong and will probably be an issue later on for testing when I want to mock this and every class gets a new instance.

I'm actually not sure why Scoped does not work here. The DbContextFactory is registered Singleton but the Context is resolved as Scoped too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it with `ServiceLifetime.Scoped`

```cs
services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(contextOptions => 
                    ... YOUR OPTIONS
), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Do you know why this is necessary? I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: its singleton by default

Comment: maybe related 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65022729/use-both-adddbcontextfactory-and-adddbcontext-extension-methods-in-the-same