# What is the difference between AddDbContextPool and AddDbContextFactory?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

Here are the codes in .NET 6 in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextPool<MyDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(connstr);
});

builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(connstr);
});
```

What is the difference between `AddDbContextPool` and `AddDbContextFactory`? What are the pro and cons of it?

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70247235/difference-between-adddbcontext-and-adddbcontextfactory

Comment: @hkarask, that link which you have provided is a comparison between `AddDbContext`  and `AddDbContextFactory`. `AddDbContext` and `AddDbContextPool` are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a consumer's standpoint, there's not much difference between `AddDbContext` and `AddDbContextPool`. In both cases, you get a **scoped** instance of a `MyDbContext` from the DI. With the pooling option, the Context gets reset rather than disposed which saves resources during the instantiation.

`AddDbContextFactory` gives you the ability to create and manage DbContext instances yourself:

```cs
using (var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
{
    // ...
}
```

That's useful when you don't have an explicit Unit of Work (e.g. request) or you want to keep the Context instance short-lived (during an intensive data pipeline task, as too many operations against the same instance can get very slow).