# Some services are not able to be constructed error while validating the service descriptor in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm building a simple ASP.NET Core Web API with Entity Framework. But while trying to run the app this error shows up:

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Middleware.Core.ApplicationService.Services.IProductService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Middleware.Core.ApplicationService.Queries.ProductService': Unable to resolve service for type 'Middleware.Infra.DataAccessLayer.ApplicationDbContextFactory' while attempting to activate 'Middleware.Core.ApplicationService.Queries.ProductService'.)'

My code is as follows - `DbContext`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

`DbContext` factory:

```
public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    private readonly DbContextOptions _options;

    public ApplicationDbContextFactory(DbContextOptions options)
    {
        _options = options;
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext(_options);
    }
}
```

One of the services

```
public class ProductService : IProductService
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContextFactory _contextFactory;

    public ProductService(ApplicationDbContextFactory contextFactory)
    {
        _contextFactory = contextFactory;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            IEnumerable<Product> products = await context.Products.ToListAsync();
            return products.Select(p => new Product() { Id = p.Id, ProductName = p.ProductName, Price = p.Price, Qty = p.Qty });
        }
    }
}
```

And my dependency injection setup:

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString), optionsLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddTransient<IProductService, ProductService>();
```

Comment: Where in your code are you registering `ApplicationDbContextFactory` as the service implementation for `IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use both AddDbContextFactory() and AddDbContext() extension methods in the same project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65022729/use-both-adddbcontextfactory-and-adddbcontext-extension-methods-in-the-same)

Comment: Please post the entire exception string.

Comment: System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Middleware.Core.ApplicationService.Services.IProductService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Middleware.Core.ApplicationService.Queries.ProductService': Unable to resolve service for type 'Middleware.Infra.DataAccessLayer.ApplicationDbContextFactory' while attempting to activate 'Middleware.Core.ApplicationService.Queries.ProductService'.)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a few issues with you code.

First of all, you never really register you factory implementation class. So you just use the default implementation of the DbContextFactory.
Change you startup/program file to something like this:

```
 builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext, ApplicationDbContextFactory>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
});
```

Then your ProductService needs to have the interface injected. Something like this:

```
public class ProductService
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> _contextFactory;

    public ProductService(IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> contextFactory)
    {
        _contextFactory = contextFactory;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            IEnumerable<Product> products = await context.Products.ToListAsync();
            return products.Select(p => new Product() { Id = p.Id, ProductName = p.ProductName, Price = p.Price, Qty = p.Qty });
        }
    }
}
```