EF Core throws ObjectDisposedException for IServiceProvider occasionally
I have a View, which causes an exception occasionally. While retrieving the initial data from the db, sometimes it fails with an ObjectDisposedException for IServiceProvider.
We are not using the type IServiceProvider directly anywhere, but EF Core is using it, since the dependent services are registered.
A new DbContext gets created per operation. What is special here, is that one db operation starts another db method to get more data to append it to the model.
This is the code:
Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
  builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("db"),
  sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(5)
), ServiceLifetime.Transient);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<LoadDataPort, LoadPurchaseService>();
[...]

DataView.razor.cs:
public partial class DataView : MyComponentBase, IDisposable
{
  [Inject] private LoadDataPort LoadDataPort { get; set; } = default!;

  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
    var purchases = await LoadDataPort.GetAllPurchases();
  }
}

LoadPurchaseService:
public class LoadPurchaseService : LoadDataPort
{  
  public async Task<List<Purchase>> GetAllPurchases()
  {
    using MyDbContext dbContext = contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
    List<Purchase> purchases = await dbContext.Purchase
                    .Include(purchase => purchase.Status)
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .OrderByDescending(n => n.SomeId)
                    .AsSplitQuery()
                    .TagWithCallSite()
                    .TagWith("GetAllPurchases")
                    .ToListAsync();
    await LoadCategoriesAsync(purchases);
    return purchases;
  }
    
  private async Task LoadCategoriesAsync(List<Purchase> purchases)
  {
    List<PurchaseCategory> allCategories = await GetAllCategoriesAsync();

    purchases.ForEach(purchase =>
    {
      List<PurchaseCategory> list = purchase.CategoriesIds
        .Where(catId => allCategories.Any(cat => cat.Id == catId))
        .Select(catId => allCategories.First(cat => cat.Id == catId))
        .ToList();
      purchase.Categories = list;
    });
  }

  public async Task<List<PurchaseCategory>> GetAllCategoriesAsync()
  {
    using MyDbContext dbContext = contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
    return await dbContext.PurchaseCategory.AsNoTracking()
      .OrderBy(category => category.Id)
      .ToListAsync();
  }
}

This throws this exception:

Unhandled exception in circuit '"xTAHc5qVVFdxpnRUv49FLQCdLHDcvwG_4Kdble8NGwg"'.
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException()
[...]
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.AsNoTracking[TEntity](IQueryable`1
source)
   at LoadPurchaseService.GetAllCategoriesAsync() in D:\source\Services\Purchase\LoadPurchaseService.cs:line 169
   at LoadPurchaseService.LoadCategoriesAsync(List`1 purchases) in D:\source\Services\Purchase\LoadPurchaseService.cs:line 151
   at LoadPurchaseService.GetAllPurchasesAsync() in D:\source\Services\Purchase\LoadPurchaseService.cs:line 44
   at Purchases.OnInitializedAsync() in D:\source\Pages\Purchases.razor.cs:line 61
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task
taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)


I am not sure what is causing this, since I cannot reproduce the error myself. I found it in our logs a few times.
It also happens rather rarely, but I would like to fix it.

Any reason why the factory service lifetime is "Transient"? In most cases, DbContextFactory itself should be a singleton unless you have a very good reason not to. DbContextFactory provisions contexts on request. Could write an answer with more technical details but it is possible the IServiceProvider has been disposed because of an earlier call to dispose from IServiceScopeFactory.

@SteelSoul is almost certainly correct here.  Scope the factory to Scoped or Singleton [the default and normal setting].  There are several reasons I can see as to why it's wrong: the most obvious is the disposal issue that applies to all transient services.   I'm sure there must be a valid reason to have it as an option, but why is above my knowledge level.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65022730/13065781

Yes, the Factory should be Singleton or Scoped, not Transient. The DbContexts it creates will be transient which you are disposing correctly. Also make sure you don't have lazy loading proxies enabled on your DbContext. When using a Transient DbContext the context will disposed at the end of the call but composing a razor view "touching" something you missed eager loading would result in a ObjectDisposedException as well. IMHO it's far safer to use a view model for read views.

I will change it to singleton. But I would expect a lifetime problem like this to throw more errors. It happens rather rarely. Any idea for a test to throw this error?

Is LoadDataPort an interface? Can you please share a full [mre]?

@GuruStron: Yes it's just an interface. It only happens occasionally, I have troubles reproducing it myself. But some user ran into it and I want to avoid it in the future.

@SteelSoul The reason for setting it to transient, was that I thought I was expecting to set the lifetime of the DbContext service. I think Microsoft updated the docs to be more precise too, now describing the parameter as factory lifetime and not just service lifetime.


System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.

This exception typically indicates that some service or its dependencies are being accessed after they have been disposed.
Using Transient may lead to lifecycle issues. It is recommended to set the Factory Singleton or Scoped. Refer to this reply.

Can you please provide a source, stating that you should not use multiple DbContext instances? Its the first time I read that.

Sorry, I don't mean that, just want to check if the issue related to the first instance's lifecycle. It's ok to use multiple DbContext instances, and I have updated my reply.

Change the lifetime of your DbContextFactory to Singleton, like such:
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
  builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("db"),
  sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(5)
));

Leave out the ServiceLifetime, because it defaults to Singleton.
